# React native splashScreen closing automatically in IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, splash-screen

react-native-splash-screen hiding automatically In IOS.
But it's fine working in android .

I followed this steps : -

1 ) npm i react-native-splash-screen --save
2 ) cd ios ,run pod install
3 ) Updated AppDelegate.m

```
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"  // here
....
 [RNSplashScreen show];  // here
....
```

4 ) CustomizeD MY splash screen via LaunchScreen.storyboard

5 )  APP.JS

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

      componentDidMount() {

        setTimeout(async() => {
            SplashScreen.hide();
        },3000);

     }
```

BUT THE SPLASH SCREEN NOT WAITING 3 SECONDS IN IOS BUT WORKING PERFECTLY IN ANDROID
ALSO IF I COMMENTED "SplashScreen.hide();" ALSO S-SCREEN IS HIDING AUTOMATICALLY in IOS.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this library https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash it supports last versions of React Native and works perfect in case you described

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: @Anshifyaseen have you tried?

Comment: Thank you, yes it's working fine .But  i can't add gradient for my splash screen

Comment: @Anshifyaseen it is another question, can you create new question with details about your screen and make this question answered?

Comment: Thanks bro https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash is working fine.But my question about react-native-splash-screen this